# text area formating not working with jquery.min.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, textarea

I am using `textarea` HTML formatting.

My HTML is:

```
<textarea type="text" name="description" id="description" value="description" rows="3"></textarea>
<div class="label-style">Description</div>
```

My `textarea` looks like this:

[image]

I have attached formatting with `textarea` `id`. `id="description"`

I also need to use on JavaScript file called `jquery.min.js`

This JavaScript also says it uses:

- Includes Sizzle.js
- http://sizzlejs.com/

The JavaScript file is: http://jsfiddle.net/cQbvN/

But when I use this class, it applies some class on my `textarea` and it looks like this:

[image]

I also tried to remove all CSS but nothing happens.

How to get `textarea` formatting buttons again back?

Comment: Where's the JavaScript that makes the text area look like that? Do you get any errors on the page?

Comment: There's no need to dump the contents of jQuery into [a jsFiddle window](http://jsfiddle.net/cQbvN/); we already know what it looks like.  And jsFiddle already includes common libraries such as jQuery as long as you select it.  Where's your JavaScript code?  Where's _your_ demo?

Comment: By default `textarea` does not include any editor buttons.  What plugin or code are you using to create that?  As written, your question is too incomplete to answer specifically.  Nicola's answer makes the most sense about what you _should_ be doing, but it's still only a generic response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are making some confusion with what you are loading, i suppose you are using a jQuery plugin to transform the textarea into a html [WYSIWYG](http://www.techtricky.com/jquery-wysiwyg-html-editors/) editor, remember that you must load jQuery before the plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-plugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#description').textarea()
} );
</script>
```

Comment: dear i am using same code but its not sowing the WYSIWYG editor, it only shows if i disable jquery.min.js which also use  * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/

Comment: @air maybe that's because you are including jQuery twice. Can you show your full markup?

Comment: dear @Nicola Peluchetti i found i dont have jquery-plugin.min.js, i was using tinyMCE, how can i download jquery.min.js